# spark sql query with percentage issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I cannot get the spark sql query with `%` sign. Let say I have the following dataframe

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("Peter",123,23.5),("John",45,45.5)))
           .toDF("Name","Age","score(%)")
df.show
```

So the table looks like this:

```
+-----+---+--------+
| Name|Age|score(%)|
+-----+---+--------+
|Peter|123|    23.5|
| John| 45|    45.5|
+-----+---+--------+
```

I can do:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT Name FROM df")
```

which shows:

```
+-----+
| Name|
+-----+
|Peter|
| John|
+-----+
```

But when I do:

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT score(%) FROM df")
```

It throws the followings: (looks like `%` is causing the issue, I tried using `\%`, but it doesn't help)

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.14] failure: ``distinct'' expected but `%' found

SELECT score(%) FROM df
             ^
  at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefaultParserDialect.parse(ParserDialect.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$3.apply(SQLContext.scala:175)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$3.apply(SQLContext.scala:175)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:115)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:114)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:137)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:217)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:197)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:217)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:882)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:882)
  at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:881)
  at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:172)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DDLParser.parse(DDLParser.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:195)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:725)
  ... 48 elided
```

(This problem is faced when I am programmed spark to ingest a large set of csv using spark-csv. When I tried to perform sql `SELECT`, I ran into this `%` issue. I would like to avoid modifying the header if possible...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using backticks to seperate column name.

```
sqlContext.sql("SELECT `score(%)` FROM df")
```